# All registers are used, what should I do? Assembly language

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, tasm

I'm making a graphical calculator and using the mouse to choose the numbers. I'm using Windows XP

I'm using INT 33h, which requires AX=3 (to click) BX=1 (check if mouse clicked) CX=horizontal coordinates, DX=vertical coordinates.

I'm getting the position of the mouse using a loop

```
MOUSEL:
 MOV AX,03H
 INT 33H
 CMP BX,1B
 JNE MOUSEL
```

And then I will check the position

```
CHECK1: 
CMP CX,200
JL  MOUSEL  
CMP CX,240  
JG  CHECK2  
CMP DX,160  
JL  MOUSEL
CMP DX,200
JG  CHECK4
MOV AL,1    
MOV [SI],AL 
<<I need a counter here>>
JE  OPERATION
```

I only want to get three numbers, store them, and then perform arithmetic operations on.
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My suggestion would be to avoid assembly language and use a good optimizing compiler (like GCC 4.8) ....

Comment: If you're writing a graphical calculator intended to run under Windows XP, why are you coding it in 16-bit DOS assembly language?

Comment: I would love to, but it is a project for college *cries*

Comment: @Zack, it's an assignment

Comment: Does the assignment specifically tell you to use *16-bit* *DOS* assembly language, or could you write a regular Windows GUI program in assembly language (with the machine in 32-bit mode and using Windows GDI calls rather than `INT 33h`)?  The latter will be *enormously* easier and will also teach you something that isn't obsolete.

Comment: yes, I have to use 16-bit DOS

Comment: OK.  In that case, well, you *have* got three free registers: you haven't used DI and BP at all, and BX is free after the `JNE MOUSEL` instruction.  Or (and this is probably the point of the exercise) you could allocate yourself a stack frame (by subtracting from SP) and then stash registers there.  Also, please tell your instructor that people on the Internet think teaching people to program 16-bit DOS nowadays is a pointless waste of time and brain capacity.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll see what I can do. I will tell him lol

Comment: but BX will be overwritten again when the mouse is clicked, I want to maintain its value. I wanted to start like this `MOV BX,3` and the `DEC BX` and `CMP BX,0' but when `JNZ` comes in it will be 1b again

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_spill

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use pusha and popa

```
  MOUSELxxx:
  pusha
  MOUSEL:
  MOV AX,03H
  INT 33H
  CMP BX,1B
  JNE MOUSEL
  popa

  CHECK1: 
  CMP CX,200
  JL MOUSELxxx

  etc
```